# ¿Por qué me manda al método show cuando estoy usando de method='PATCH' para que me dirija a update?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7

Tengo el código del controlador que es este:

```
 public function edit($id)
{
    $admin=DB::table('admin as adm')
        ->join('users as u', 'adm.id_admin', '=', 'u.u_admin_id')
        ->select('adm.adm_no', 'adm.adm_nombre', 'adm.adm_apellido1', 'adm.adm_fecha_nacimiento',
            'adm.adm_activo', 'u.name as nombre', 'u.email as email')
        ->where('adm.adm_no', '=', $id)->get();

    return view("admin.edit", ["admin"=>$admin]);
}

public function update(AdminFormRequest $request, $id)
{
    DB::table('admin as adm')

        ->where('adm.adm_no', '=', $id)

        ->update(['adm.adm_nombre' => $request->get('adm_nombre'),
            'adm.adm_apellido1'=> $request->get('adm_apellido1'),
            'adm.adm_fecha_nacimiento'=> $request->get('adm_fecha_nacimiento')]);

    DB::table('users as u')

        ->join('admin as adm', 'adm.id_admin', '=', 'u.u_admin_id')

        ->where('adm.adm_no', '=', $id)

        ->update(['u.name'=>$request->get('name'),
            'u.email'=>$request->get('email'),
            'u.password'=>$request->get('password')]);


    return Redirect::to('admin.index');
}
```

y el código de la vista es el siguiente:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Update</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="PATCH" action="{{ route('admin.update', $admin[0], $admin[0]->adm_no) }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                                       value="{{ $admin[0]->nombre }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('adm_nombre') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="adm_nombre" class="col-md-4 control-label">Nombre</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="adm_nombre" type="text" class="form-control" name="adm_nombre"
                                       value="{{ $admin[0]->adm_nombre }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('adm_nombre'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('adm_nombre') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('adm_apellido1') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="adm_apellido1" class="col-md-4 control-label">Apellido1</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="adm_apellido1" type="text" class="form-control" name="adm_apellido1"
                                       value="{{ $admin[0]->adm_apellido1 }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('adm_apellido1'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('adm_apellido1') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <label for="adm_fecha_nacimiento" class="col-md-4 control-label">Fecha Nacimiento</label>

                        <div class="well">

                            <input class="date" type="text" id="adm_fecha_nacimiento" value="{{$admin[0]->adm_fecha_nacimiento}}"
                                   name="adm_fecha_nacimiento"></input>

                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $admin[0]->email }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Actualizar datos
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Supuestamente tendría que mandar los datos al metodo update y de ahí redirigirme al método index pero por algo que no comprendo me manda al método show cuando no lo tengo definido:
[image: Method [show] does not exist on [libreir\Http\Controllers\AdminController].]

Las rutas son las siguientes:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\libreir>php artisan route:list
+--------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                                            | Name                    | Action                                                                     | Middleware      |
+--------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                                              |                         | Closure                                                                    | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin                                          | admin.index             | libreir\Http\Controllers\AdminController@index                             | web,admin,auth  |
|        | POST      | admin                                          | admin.store             | libreir\Http\Controllers\AdminController@store                             | web,admin,auth  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/create                                   | admin.create            | libreir\Http\Controllers\AdminController@create                            | web,admin,auth  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/{admin}                                  | admin.show              | libreir\Http\Controllers\AdminController@show                              | web,admin,auth  |
|        | DELETE    | admin/{admin}                                  | admin.destroy           | libreir\Http\Controllers\AdminController@destroy                           | web,admin,auth  |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/{admin}                                  | admin.update            | libreir\Http\Controllers\AdminController@update                            | web,admin,auth  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/{admin}/edit                             | admin.edit              | libreir\Http\Controllers\AdminController@edit                              | web,admin,auth  |
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega las rutas respectivas, y el contenido respectivo de artisan route:list

Comment: Ya está actualizado, gracias por contestar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resulta que los formularios en HTML solo pueden aceptar dos verbos: GET y POST, por lo cual ahí tienes un error, lo que Laravel hace para poder "recibir" los otros verbos es utilizar un campo adicional:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.update', $admin[0], $admin[0]->adm_no) }}">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

En cuanto a lo que veo en tu estructura de rutas, no hay nada mal aparentemente, probablemente estés usando `Route::resource()`

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirvió de mucho, la verdad antes estaba utilizando {!!Form::open(array('url'=>'almacen/autor', 'method'=> 'POST' , 'autocomplete'=> 'off')) !!}
    {{Form::token()}} pero vi que quedaban mal las vistas y por eso me decidí a cambiar.

Comment: Si usas el form builder de Collective, ahí si puedes utilizar PUT o PATCH o DELETE, pues el hace la "conversión" por ti.